# Extracting the different length strings from the middle of a string

Tags: excel, formulas

I am trying to extract the DocType (VARG, NOR, RMRN, CHNG, ADCN) from the middle of the below worksheet.  As you can see, there is nothing consistent within the different strings. I am trying to extract the doctype embedded within the string and place it in the corresponding doctype cell to the left of the drawing sheet cell.  Alas, I cannot determine a formula to do so.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
DocType     Drawing Sheet
            100188-NOR03046
            10190635-VARG003-V-013R1
            10190635-VARG003-V-018
            1086-CHNG121701
            10908077-RMRNR0190
            11613002-NOR1-1
            11627748-NOR07146
            11639519-ADCN30352
            116-NOR6458
            11664680-NOR75941R1
            12292527-NORGEO-5343
            12292400-NORWIP09335
            12292527-NORGEO-5343
```

I have used this formula:

=MID(I679,SEARCH("-",I679)+1,IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(I679,SEARCH("-",I679)+4,1))),4,3))

but for the values listed below I got the following results:

```
DocType     Drawing Sheet               Correct Result Should Be
NORG        12292527-NORGEO-5343        NOR
NORW        12292400-NORWIP09335        NOR
VARG        10190635-VARG003-V-013R1    VAR
VARG        12292-VARG003-V-016         VAR
R-AD        12295729-R-ADCN167238       ADCN
31-A        12359705-31-ADCN71449       ADCN
R2-A        RM12293172-R2-ADCN183214    ADCN
129         RM-12976612-RM2-ADCN183868  ADCN
19-         B5-19-1676-NORFSV00098R1    NOR
NORW        12517164-NORWIP10095        NOR
```

If you need anymore examples just let me know.

I also tried the following formula but it just produced the 0 (zero):

```
=IF(I9="*VAR*","VAR",IF(I9="*ADCN*","ADCN",IF(I9="*CHNG*","CHNG",IF(I9="*DEVN*",‌​"DEVN",IF(I9="*EER*","EER",IF(I9="*NOR*","NOR",IF(I9="*PPEP*","PPEP",IF(I9="*RMRN‌*​","RMRN",IF(I9="*SCN*","SCN",IF(I9="*WAIV*","WAIV",0))))))))))
```

Comment: Are there only the five doctypes as stated? Or can the doctype be NORGEO etc?

Comment: And precisely which part IS the doctype in each case? For example, in line 2, is it VARG003-V-018 or just VARG003? Perhaps you should add your expected results to your table.

Comment: There are a few of the doctypes already list in the above question, but a complete list of the doctype are:  ADCN, CHNG, DEVN, EER, NOR, PPEP, RMRN, SCN, VAR, WAIV.  So in the case of the NORGEO, the doctype is NOR.

Comment: I also tried this absurd formula but I get the zero everytime.  Can anyone tell my why because it seems sound.                                                     =IF(I9="*VAR*","VAR",IF(I9="*ADCN*","ADCN",IF(I9="*CHNG*","CHNG",IF(I9="*DEVN*","DEVN",IF(I9="*EER*","EER",IF(I9="*NOR*","NOR",IF(I9="*PPEP*","PPEP",IF(I9="*RMRN*","RMRN",IF(I9="*SCN*","SCN",IF(I9="*WAIV*","WAIV",0))))))))))

Comment: Your formula is incorrect because I9 does not "=" "VAR", it *contains* "VAR". Does 5 = 50? No, 50 contains 5.

Comment: So the * before the VAR and after the VAR doesn't work in this case?  Not sure why they didn't copy over.

Comment: The comments box isn't copying the * over but it should be like this:  I9="(STAR)VAR(STAR)", where the (STAR) is a *.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for the case where the required substring is preceded by the first hyphen in the string and followed by the next hyphen or digit:-

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)),
MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"-"},RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)))),
FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"-"},RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)))))-1)
```

[image]

If you have a list of the possible document types you can search for them like this:-

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX({"ADCN","CHNG","DEVN","EER","NOR","PPEP","RMRN","SCN","VAR","WAIV"},
MATCH("ZZZ",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND( {"ADCN","CHNG","DEVN","EER","NOR","PPEP","RMRN","SCN","VAR","WAIV"},B2)),
{"ADCN","CHNG","DEVN","EER","NOR","PPEP","RMRN","SCN","VAR","WAIV"}))),
"")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The doctypes should be ADCN, CHNG, DEVN, EER, NOR, PPEP, RMRN, SCN, VAR, WAIV.  So in your example row 5-6 should be VAR, row 8 should be RMRN, row 14-16 should be NOR.

Comment: Have added this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

"...there is nothing consistent within the different strings" - incorrect. From what I can see, the first 3-4 characters after the first "-" contain the data type. 3 Characters if the 4th character is a number. Use whatever data uniformity exists to create your tests that align your data as needed.

This could work like so [assuming your data starts in B2, this formula goes in C2, and gets dragged down]:

```
=SEARCH("-",B2)
```

This gives you the character placement of the first "-" in the cell. Then put this in D2 and drag down:

```
=ISERROR(VALUE(MID(B2,C2+4,1)))
```

This attempts to convert the character 4 spaces after the "-" into a value. If it's a letter, it will create an error, which results in TRUE. Otherwise it will show FALSE.

Then put this in E2 and drag down:

```
=MID(B2,C2+1,IF(D2,4,3))
```

This says - take cell B2, and, starting at the character after the "-", return the text that goes for 3-4 characters. If D2 is TRUE [there was an error in the above formula, meaning the 4th character was not a number], it goes for 4 spaces. Otherwise if D2 is FALSE, it goes for 3 spaces.

This can alternatively all be placed in a single formula in C2 as follows:

```
=MID(B2,SEARCH("-",B2)+1,IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(B2,SEARCH("-",B2)+4,1))),4,3))
```

Comment: OK...this get the closest yet, but I still get a few that are not correct.  I have listed the code, value, and results of a few.  10190635-VARG003-V-013R1 with the code of =MID(I20,SEARCH("-",I20)+1,IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(I20,SEARCH("-",I20)+4,1))),4,3)) gives me the result of VARG and it should be VAR.  12292527-NORGEO-5343 with the code of =MID(I679,SEARCH("-",I679)+1,IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(I679,SEARCH("-",I679)+4,1))),4,3)) gives me the result of NORG and it should be NOR.

Comment: @Todd I have confirmed that this works for the data you have listed in your example. What other 'corner cases' (ie: unusual data inputs) exist? edit your question to include this information, instead of putting it in comments.